# Shuffle NSMutableArray with 'Shuffle Albums' for up next queue (MediaPlayer)?

Tags: ios, algorithm, swift, nsmutablearray, mpmediaitem

I have managed to create an up next queuing system that works (almost) perfectly. I can move, delete and add songs to the list without any issues at all. The only problem i am having is that when the user decides to use a shuffle mode (e.g. `MPMusicShuffleMode`.Songs), the up next view still displays the old order (assumes shuffle mode is set to off). The app Ecoute has a similar queuing system but it also works when shuffling.

I've realized that Ecoute does not use the `MPMusicShuffleMode`, if you go into the stock music player after pressing shuffle in Ecoute, it stays the same. I've figured out a way to display the correct order for shuffled songs (just shuffle the `NSMutableArray` and set this as the new queue). The real problem is how would i shuffle this array when the user wants to 'Shuffle Albums'? The `NSMutableArray` contains `MPMediaItem` if that helps.

Many thanks.

EDIT:

This attempt works but the time grows exponentially for the number of songs. 2000 songs took about 25-35 seconds, so very slow.

```
else if(self.shuffleMode == "Songs"){
        self.shuffleMode = "Albums"
        self.shuffle.setTitle("Shuffle Albums", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        var queueCopy = NSMutableArray(array: self.queue.items)
        var newQueue = NSMutableArray(array: [])

        var albums = MPMediaQuery.albumsQuery().collections as [MPMediaItemCollection]
        var albumsCopy = NSMutableArray(array: albums)
        shuffleArray(albumsCopy)

        for album in albumsCopy{
            for item in queueCopy{
                if (album.representativeItem!.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle) as NSString == item.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle) as NSString){
                    for(var i = 0; i < album.items!.count; i++){
                        if(album.items![i].valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyTitle) as NSString == item.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyTitle) as NSString){
                            newQueue.addObject(item as MPMediaItem)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        let newQueueToSet = MPMediaItemCollection(items: newQueue)
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
        appDelegate.currentQueue = newQueueToSet
        self.queue = newQueueToSet

        self.player.setQueueWithItemCollection(newQueueToSet)

}
```

EDIT 2:

Managed to get it down to 8 seconds but it's nowhere near Ecoute's 1 to 2 seconds.
8 second version:

```
        var albumNames = [String]()
        for item in queueCopy{
            albumNames.append(item.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle) as NSString)
        }

        let unique = NSSet(array: albumNames).allObjects as [MPMediaItem]
        var uniqueAlbumNames = NSMutableArray(array: unique)
        shuffleArray(uniqueAlbumNames)

        for name in uniqueAlbumNames{
            for item in queueCopy{
                if item.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle) as NSString == name as NSString{
                    newQueue.addObject(item as MPMediaItem)
            }
        }
}
```

Final Edit:

final piece of code that i'm sticking with. takes about 7-8 seconds for nearly 3000 songs.

```
    @IBAction func shufflePressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    if self.shuffleMode == "Off"{
        self.shuffleMode = "Songs"
        self.shuffle.setTitle("Shuffle All", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        self.shuffle.setTitle("Shuffling", forState: UIControlState.Highlighted)


        var queueCopy = NSMutableArray(array: self.queue.items)
        self.unshuffledQueueCopy = self.queue

        shuffleArray(queueCopy)
        let newQueue = MPMediaItemCollection(items: queueCopy)
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
        appDelegate.currentQueue = newQueue
        self.queue = newQueue

        self.player.setQueueWithItemCollection(newQueue)

    }
    else if(self.shuffleMode == "Songs"){
        self.shuffleMode = "Albums"
        self.shuffle.setTitle("Shuffle Albums", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        var queueCopy = NSMutableArray(array: self.queue.items)
        var newQueue = NSMutableArray(array: [])

        var albums = MPMediaQuery.albumsQuery().collections as [MPMediaItemCollection]
        var albumsCopy = NSMutableArray(array: albums)
        shuffleArray(albumsCopy)


        // Takes 8 seconds for 3000 songs

        var albumNames = [String]()

        for item in queueCopy{
            albumNames.append(item.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle) as NSString)
        }

        let unique = NSSet(array: albumNames).allObjects as [MPMediaItem]
        var uniqueAlbumNames = NSMutableArray(array: unique)
        shuffleArray(uniqueAlbumNames)


        for name in uniqueAlbumNames{
            for item in queueCopy{
                if item.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle) as NSString == name as NSString{
                    newQueue.addObject(item as MPMediaItem)
                }
            }
        }

        let newQueueToSet = MPMediaItemCollection(items: newQueue)
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
        appDelegate.currentQueue = newQueueToSet
        self.queue = newQueueToSet

        self.player.setQueueWithItemCollection(newQueueToSet)

    }
    else if(self.shuffleMode == "Albums"){
        self.shuffleMode = "Off"
        self.shuffle.setTitle("Shuffle", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        var queueCopy = NSMutableArray(array: self.unshuffledQueueCopy.items)
        var nowPlayingItem = self.player.nowPlayingItem
        for(var i = 0; i < queueCopy.count; i++){
            if(queueCopy[i] as MPMediaItem == nowPlayingItem){
                self.fromIndex = i
            }
        }
        let newQueue = MPMediaItemCollection(items: queueCopy)
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
        appDelegate.currentQueue = newQueue
        self.queue = newQueue

        self.player.setQueueWithItemCollection(newQueue)
        self.fromItem = newQueue.items[fromIndex + 1] as MPMediaItem

    }
```

Comment: So is your question about how to shuffle some items in an NSMutableArray?

Comment: @Avt yes but by album instead of song

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in pseudo code it would look something like the following.

1. Loop the Array making a new array of the albums only
2. Shuffle the new Albums array
3. Loop the new albums array, looking through the original array for items in that album.
4. On match, write those songs into a third array which will become your new playlist.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I believe this worked. For my step one, i created a new array from an albums query and then followed the rest.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not the most efficient. It takes a very long time to shuffle through 2000 songs on an iPhone 6. I have added the code above to see if you can spot a quicker way. Thanks

Comment: Looking at your code above, I'd make the second stage when pulling out the albums,  a dictionary.  Containing album->tracks. Then when re-populating it would be adding whole arrays of items.  That might be quicker.  But really you have to profile the code and see what is slow.  Do you know which pets use the most time?

Comment: It might be that accessing the meta information on those MPMediaItem's is the slow part so if you group the data without the need to keep looking within the music item you will see a speed increase.

Comment: I'm certain that Ecoute uses an undocumented API. It is impossible to get that speed otherwise. What i have right now will do, it's very quick when working with playlists so that's alright. I've marked yours as the answer as it helped a lot. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, you'd really have to go through it with a fine toothed comb to really squeeze every last ms out of it.  But also you might consider permanently storing the structured data and then just shuffle it when you need to.  Tricky, there are always compromises to be made.